flex item not shrinking less than width
I can't understand why aren't the cards shrinking post 300px. Based on my understanding of flexbox, if there is no available space, flex-shrink comes into play.
What's interesting to me is that when i use flex-basis instead of width, it works perfectly fine and it shrinks normally; But when it is set to auto which if im not mistaken falls back to width, it just overflows the container width and i can't understand why there is no shrinking.
I know that i can fix the overflow by using flex-wrap: wrap, but the problem is that i can't understand the behaviour.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.footer {
  height: 72px;
  background: #eee;
  color: darkmagenta;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  background: royalblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 300px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
}

.cards {
  padding: 48px;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  gap: 32px;
}
<div class="header">
  MY AWESOME WEBSITE
</div>

<div class="main-section">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">⭐ - link one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">️ - link three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> - link four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit corrupti veritatis minima porro?</div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit ea.
    </div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?
    </div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?
    </div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  The Odin Project ❤️
</div>




add min-width: 0 to .cards

I tried that, it didnt work either. Also with flex-basis instead of width, there is no need for min-width and it will shrink normally.

to cards not card (and it does work)

Thank you so much. But why does it work when we just use flex-basis instead of width?

read the duplicate to understand why
